# Advantage of quantum computers over classical computers in fully modeling interactions between atoms?

Tags: simulation, classical-computing, quantum-advantage, chemistry

I'm trying to better understand the advantage quantum computers offer in terms of their ability to more accurately model chemical reactions. As a way to come to a deeper understanding, my question is:

How much computing power would a classical computer need to fully simulate the interaction between two carbon atoms versus how much computing power would a quantum computer need to do the same?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! However I have removed your second question so that this post doesn't get "closed for asking more than one question in the post".